# Process of deploying on Heroku - what happens on the host?

Tags: python, git, heroku, flask, hosting

I have recently deployed my first website on Heroku. 
To do my first deploying, I followed slavishly the following tutorial:
[Deploying Flask Apps Using Heroku](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=skc-ZEU9kO8&index=17&list=PL9EzS5uVcQiEx9BQYiPmaItYEkjzkshvu&t=16s)
So, every time I want to load my site on the hosting service of Heroku, I execute the following commands (after entering in *env* mode):

> git add . 
> git commit -m "commit number X" 
> git push heroku master

Everything works beautifully, but now I would like to continue to make changes to my codes without interfering with the changes made by users.
For example, users of this site may have uploaded files that are sorted into the various folders on the site, in particular in the *data* folder (according to the classical structure of a Flask project as sampled below):

```
├── mySite/ 
│   ├── .gitignore 
│   ├── app.py 
│   ├── nltk.txt 
│   ├── procfile 
│   ├── requirements.txt 
│   ├── .git/ 
│   ├── env/ 
│   ├── templates/ 
│   └── static/ 
│       ├── css/ 
│       ├── data/ 
│       ├── img/ 
│       ├── js/
```

Now I would like to continue working on the site for example, modifying the various codes like python javascript, html and css, perhaps even deleting some of them.
Summing up, by executing the commands listed in the blockquote, is there a risk that I can interfere with the changes made by users inside the *data* folder? If there is a risk, how can I do to update only certain files?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to add the data folder in the .gitignore .

Comment: In the _.gitignore_ file there is only one word: `env`, which indicates the _env_ folder. To add _data_ or subfolders, just write `static/data/mySubFolder` after _env_ in a new line?

Comment: Try doing this: `static/data/mySubFolder/*`